# How to summarise dataframe by way of majority votes of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a really tricky statistics that I want to produce. My `dataframe` contains information about true classes and prediction results of a machine learning model, for trips and corresponding trips' segments. The problem can best be explained with example, so I give the following example `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'trip': [25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 54, 54, 54, 54,73,73,73,75,75], 
     'segment': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,0,0,1,1,3], 
     'class': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1,2,2,2,1,1], 
     'prediction': [0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1,4,2,4,0,2]
     }
)

df
   trip segment class prediction
0   25    0      3      0
1   25    0      3      0
2   25    0      3      3
3   25    0      3      3
4   25    0      3      3
5   25    1      3      4
6   25    1      3      4
7   25    1      3      2
8   25    1      3      2
9   54    2      1      0
10  54    2      1      0
11  54    2      1      1
12  54    2      1      1
13  73    0      2      4
14  73    0      2      2
15  73    1      2      4
16  75    1      1      0
17  75    3      1      2
```

From the given `df`, I would like to produce statistics of model's predictions at `trip` and `segment` levels, using `prediction`'s majority votes, considering the actual `class` a `trip` or `segment`  belongs to.

**Segment's statistics**

So considering the above `df`, I would like to produce the below segment's statistics (explanation given below):

```
class total-segments  correctly-predicted  accuracy-rate
  0       -                  -                  -
  1       3                  1                 0.33
  2       2                  1                 0.5
  3       2                  1                 0.5
  4       -                  -                  -
```

- no segment of `class` `0`, so the dash.
- there are 3 distinct segments of `class` type `1`(segment `2` of trip `54` and segments `1` & `3` of trip `75`). Of all the 3, only one (segment `2` of trip `54` has majority votes of its `prediction` correct, so `1` `correctly-predicted` and `0.33` (i.e. `1/3`)  accuracy-rate.
- there're 2 segments belonging to `class` type `2` ( segments `0`& `1` of trip `73`). Segment `0` has majority votes correct, so `1` `correctly-predicted` and `0.5` (i.e. `1/2`)  accuracy-rate.
- there're 2 segments of `class` `3` (segments `0` & `1` of trip `25`). Segment `0` has majority votes correct, so `1` `correctly-predicted` and `0.5` (i.e. `1/5`)  accuracy-rate.
- no segment of `class` type `4`.

**Trip-level statistics**

Similarly, considering the `class` type of distinct trips in `df` and their `prediction`, I want to produce the following trip-level statistics (also explained below):

```
class total-trips  correctly-predicted  accuracy-rate
  0       -                  -                  -
  1       2                  1                 0.5
  2       1                  0                 0.0
  3       1                  1                 1.0
  4       -                  -                  -
```

- no trip belongs to `class` `0`.
- 2 trips of `class` type `1`(trip `54` & `75`). 1 trip was predicted correct (majority votes of trip `54`), so `1` `correctly-predicted` trip, and `0.5` `accuracy-rate`.
- 1 trip of `class` `2` (trip `73`). Its majority votes prediction is incorrect, so `0` `correctly-predicted` trip, and `0.0` `accuracy-rate`.
- 1 trip of `class` `3` (trip `25`). Its majority votes prediction is correct (`3`),  so `1` `correctly-predicted` trip, and `1.0` `accuracy-rate`.
- no trip of `class 4`.

Please forgive the long grammar, but this is a problem that one can understand only when well-explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way. you can comment all but the first line and then uncomment one by one to see what is happening with the command line.

```
res_seg = (
    df['class'].eq(df['prediction'])
      .groupby([df['class'],df['segment']]).mean()
      .ge(0.5)
      .groupby(level='class').agg(['size','sum'])
      .rename(columns={'size':'total_segments','sum':'correctly_predicted'})\
      .assign(accuracy_rate = lambda x: x['correctly_predicted']/x['total_segments'])
      .reindex(range(5), fill_value='-')
      .reset_index()
)
print(res_seg)
#    class total_segments correctly_predicted accuracy_rate
# 0      0              -                   -             -
# 1      1              3                   1      0.333333
# 2      2              2                   1           0.5
# 3      3              2                   1           0.5
# 4      4              -                   -             -
```

and similar for the trips, you would have to change the `df['segment']` to `df['trip']` in the groupby and maybe the name of the columns in the `rename` as well as the `assign`

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what `.ge(0.5)` means (and does) please?

Comment: after the `groupby.mean` you get the percentage of good prediction, then you compare to 0.5 (`ge` means greater or equal) so it says if the segment of the class has a majority of well predicted class